# Google drive API returns empty list to queries on 'photos' space

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the drive api drive.files.list for the photos space is returning empty file lists. If I do not specify a space, I get a list of files, some of which are members of both the drive and photos spaces, as shown here:

Query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&fields=files&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response (lots of file metadata, including files with 'spaces' property like this):

```
..."spaces": ["photos","drive"],...
```

However if I query looking for files from the 'photos' space, I get this:

Query:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&spaces=photos&fields=files&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{"files": []}
```

So it seems I have the permissions correct since it will return to me all file information if 'space' is not specified, however adding the filter constraint of 'photos' to the 'space' property causes no file metadata to be returned (empty list).

This feature worked for the last couple of years, and recently seems to have broken.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current stage, photos space is introduced as deprecated.

> (DEPRECATED) The photos space includes all images and videos uploaded to Google Photos.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-organization#spaces

Because Google Photos was updated recently. (About this, you may have already known.) By this update, files in Google Photos are retrieved by the Drive API's endpoint without `spaces=photos`. If you want to retrieve only files in Google Photos, please use `q`.

#### If you can see the folder of "Google Photos" on your Google Drive

You can retrieve files in Google Photos using folder ID as follows.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%22### folder ID of Google Photos ###%22+in+parents&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

#### If you cannot see the folder of "Google Photos"

From your question, you may have already done the following setting. If you have already done, please ignore this.

If you cannot see the folder of "Google Photos", please access to https://support.google.com/photos?p=drive, and check the document. When Google Drive is enabled, you can see the folder and retrieve the folder ID. In this situation, files and folders in "Google Photos" become `"spaces": ["drive"]`.

If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: You are correct! They have deprecated 'photos'. For anyone else trying this, you can set the query for "Google Photos" but it will return both the new one (created by Google in your My Drive directory) and the old one (created by Google at the top level as a sibling to My Drive). However, the old one is marked 'trashed = true', so if your query string is
   `name = 'Google Photos' and trashed = false`
you will find the correct one (unless you have other Google Photo folders or files lying about...)  Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: @labroid Thank you for your additional information. I could study from your question and comments. Thank you, too.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the above workaround. Just want to add that one needs to first retrieve the id of the "Google Photos" folder based on `title` in v2 API or `name` in v3 API and then call the drive API with `q` as @Tanaike has answered.