# Using Google.Apis.Core for .NET Core, why can't i see a list of photos in my Google Photos when I specify spaces="photos"?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Sample code goes like this:

```
static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DrivePhotosReadonly };
static string ApplicationName = "Quickstart";

UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.Spaces = "photos";
            listRequest.PageSize = 100;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
```

I enable the Google Drive API through the Google Console and get the credentials.json file.  When I run this using listRequest.Spaces = "drive" then I can see all of my drive files, but I cannot see any photos when I make it "photos".

What other sort of undocumented magic needs to be in place here for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: to me that would imply that you have no photos in the photos space.  remove listRequest.Spaces and start searching on media types.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive and Google Photos have been [disconnected](https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/), the space "photos" has been [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879209/11599789).

However, there is a [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos) that allows you to [list](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/list) your photos.